# What is this gigantic dish at Ben Gurion airport?

Tags: airport, feature-identification

As the title asks, what is this thing for?  Have never seen anything like it at other airports I've been to.

[image]

Comment: Is it just for decorative purposes by any chance?

Comment: It's probably some insane technology hiding in plain sight. That would be *soooo Israel*...

Comment: Totally [just a decoration](https://live.staticflickr.com/4163/33516776124_b6c28a8037_b.jpg). Fire at will, commander.

Comment: It would be a great place for an endurance bike race, ["The Long Walk"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Long_Walk) style. If you're too slow, you fall from the velodrome, down into a pit.

Comment: Skate rink, of course!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It is just a design feature, and serves no technical purpose, beyond filtering some light and providing a waterfall feature.

> Safdie designed the roof of the rotunda as an inverted dome, an asymmetric dish floating above the piazza that lets sunlight in and filters the daylight with a special white fabric ceiling.
>   <sub>source: https://www.bdcnetwork.com/ready-takeoff</sub>

and

> Rain falling upon the suspended dome drains towards the center and enters the rotunda through an oculus skylight as a waterfall. In the dry season, a continuous flow of water washes the roof, contributing to the rotunda’s cooling and forming a fountain through the oculus.
>   <sub>source: https://www.safdiearchitects.com/projects/ben-gurion-intl-airport-airside-terminal</sub>

Image, because it looks nice (Same source as second quote above)

[image]

Comment: `"that lets sunlight in and filters the daylight with a special white fabric ceiling"` well that **is** a technical purpose, won't you agree?

Comment: @DeepSpace That seems to be the purpose of the 'special white fabric ceiling', not the dome design itself

Comment: @Rob: But still the **dish** serves a technical purpose just like any other possible roof for the building. The question could have been simply answered by: The dish serves as roof for the building ;-)

Answer (score 11):

It's Architecture [sic], and it's for your eyes to behold:

[Safdie architects explain further.](https://www.safdiearchitects.com/projects/ben-gurion-intl-airport-airside-terminal)

[image]

Comment: Why did you write `[sic]`?

Comment: Because this is architecture with a capital letter :)

Answer (score 4):

This is the decorative roof above the duty-free area, which is circular with a plaza in its center. From the top center and around the "sun roof" there a circular waterfall.